# Is there a standard way to create a CSV value from a string[]?

Tags: c#, algorithm, csv, refactoring, richtextbox

I want to create a CSV string from the items in a richtextbox. I know there's got to be a better way than the one I cobbled together:

```
string CSVDuckbills = GetLinesAsCSV(richTextBoxDuckbills.Lines);
...
private string GetLinesAsCSV(string[] DuckbillLines)
{
    string DuckbillCSV = string.Empty;
    foreach (string item in DuckbillLines)
    {
        DuckbillCSV += string.Format("{0},", item);
    }
    return DuckbillCSV;
}
```

For one thing, I will have to strip off a superfluous comma at the end.

Comment: beyond that, you're also using string concatenation which would be horribly slow depending on the number of elements.  For future reference, when building dynamic strings out of collections like this you should use the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) for simpler:

```
string DuckbillCSV = string.Join(",", DuckbillLines);
```

Comment: What about the newline in the end of each line?

Comment: @fableal: the code sample does not have you you can easily to use "\n"

Comment: "\n" is a unix/linux line break. macs use \r and windows \r\n. Environment.NewLine might be a better way of getting the systems line break ... unless the app only runs on *nix.

Comment: I don't want the line breaks. I just want a value such as: "Gallagher,Santana,Betts,Clapton,Brown,Gibbons"

Comment: Using each data entry as a column is not a CSV.

Comment: @fableal Any values that are separated by a comma are comma-separated values.

Comment: No problem, I just fell confused to see such an application of a csv (unless you are using this as a template for inserting more data ... never mind).

Comment: Don't forget to check for line breaks or commas inside the fields and either remove them or quote-escape the field.  If you quote escape the field then you also need to escape quotes inside of the field.